# Perfect forwarding with a specific type

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding

When writing a threadsafe `std::stack` wrapper I made the following two overloads for `push`:

```cpp
void push(const value_type& value)
{
    auto guard = std::scoped_lock{_mutex};
    _stack.push(value);
    _cv.notify_one();
}

void push(value_type&& value)
{
    auto guard = std::scoped_lock{_mutex};
    _stack.push(std::move(value));
    _cv.notify_one();
}
```

They are nearly the same except that one takes a const l-value reference and one takes an r-value reference. Normally I would use perfect forwarding to deal with this (now using the glorious C++20 abbreviated template declaration):

```cpp
void push(auto&& value)
{
    auto guard = std::scoped_lock{_mutex};
    _stack.push(std::forward<decltype(value)>(value));
    _cv.notify_one();
}
```

The problem here is that this accepts any type, while it should accept only `value_type` and references to it.

Is there some standard way to solve this? So far I came up with two approches. Either use a `std::enable_if` to somehow check if the template type is `value_type` or a reference to it, or use a concept.

Comment: You could also use `static_assert`. Or you could just not bother, because `push(...)` itself will fail to compile if the value's type is incorrect.

Comment: Both approaches you mentioned don’t allow conversions, e.g. for a value type of double push(0) won’t work. I myself don’t have a better solution, I use the concept approach.

Comment: Use [`std::is_convertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) instead.

Comment: So auto&& will handle l-values and r-vals? I am always like 5 years behind ... I'll probably understand the C++20 features in 2025.

Comment: @wcochran `void foo(auto&&)` is syntactic sugar for `template <typename T> void foo(T&&)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert it:

```
template<typename T>
void push(T&& value)
{
    static_assert(is_same_v<remove_reference_t<T>, value_type>);
    // ...
}
```

You could alternatively use `is_convertible` instead of `is_same` so it works more naturally.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried to delete the answer immediately and edit that part as soon as I noticed it, and you still managed to leave the comment :-)

Comment: What can I say, I'm a ninja ;)  You should consider using `std::is_convertible` instead of `std::is_same` so that things that could be converted to `value_type` are also accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I repeat `@Ayxan Haqverdili`'s example in multiple versions. Also note, because you mention that you want a *standard way to solve this*, that `C++20` concepts are the standard way now. Unless you are writing code that requires compatibility with old language versions, that should be used. The primary reason is that it clearly and concisely documents the requirements of the function at the declaration site. This is even more eloquent than `static_assert`, and allows overloading instead of direct failure. `std::enable_if` is simply the old method of instating requirement.

#### An Inline Concept

```cpp
template <class T>
    requires std::convertible_to<T, value_type>
void push(T &&value);
```

#### A Custom Concept

This lets you use the convenient parameter `auto`.

```cpp
template <class T, class U>
concept ForwardType = std::convertible_to<T, U>

void push(ForwardType<value_type> auto &&value);
```

#### Using `std::enable_if`

This should be compatible with C++11.

```cpp
template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T>> push(T &&value);
```